# Export mysql database tables to php code to create same tables in other database?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I Export mysql database tables to php code so that it allows me to create and populate same tables in other database?

I have a local database, I exported to sql syntax, then I get something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `boletinSuscritos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `boletinSuscritos` VALUES(1, 'walter', 'waltermazzola@hotmail.com', '2010-03-24 12:53:12');
INSERT INTO `boletinSuscritos` VALUES(2, 'Paco', 'paco@arroba.com', '2010-03-24 12:56:56');
```

---

but I need it to be: (Is there any way to export the tables in this way)

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE  boletinSuscritos  (
   id  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name  varchar(120) NOT NULL,
   email  varchar(120) NOT NULL,
   date  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 )";

mysql_query($sql,$conexion);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO boletinSuscritos  VALUES(1, 'walter', 'pepe@hotmail.com', '2010-03-24 12:53:12')");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO boletinSuscritos  VALUES(2, 'Paco', 'paco@arroba.com', '2010-03-24 12:56:56')");
```

Comment: sorry about the lack of breaklines, but when creating this question it looks with breaklines...

Comment: There's a button to format the codes. http://i.imgur.com/29ueO.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your databases to a file using this command:

- **mysqldump -u username -p password dbname > dump.sql**

If you would prefer to only dump the structure of the database:

- **mysqldump -u username -p password –no-data dbname > dump.sql**

You can then import your database using a similar command:

- **mysql -u username -p password dbname < dump.sql**

Since you want to do this from within php, you can do something along these lines:

```
$result = 0;
$command = "mysqldump -u username -p password dbname > dump.sql";
exec($command,$output=array(),$result);
if($result) echo "yay, this has worked.\n";
```

You may be able to find more examples by figuring out how [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) does it, or checking out [MySQL's Load Data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) function.

Comment: I understand that I need to run these commands in the Terminal (mac) right? Problem for me is that I use MAMP and the Terminal doesn't realize that mysql is installed then the mysql commands doesn't work in the terminal. I'll take a look at the link you posted. Thanks